# Anagram generator from input in Python malfunction

Tags: python, loops, random, anagram

I tried to code a simple generator of a list of anagrams from an input. But after I rewrote the code it gives me only 2 outputs. Here's the code

```
import random
item=input("Name? ")
a=''
b=''
oo=0
while oo<=(len(item)*len(item)):
    a=''.join([str(y) for y in random.sample(item, len(item))]) #this line was found on this site
    b=''.join([str(w) for w in random.sample(item, len(item))]) #because in no way i had success in doing it by myself
    j=[]
    j.append(a) #During the loop it should add the anagrams generated
    j.append(b) #everytime the loop repeats itself
    oo=oo+1
j=list(set(j)) #To cancel duplicates
h=len(j)
f=0
while f<=(h-1):
    print(j[f])
```

But the output it gives is only one anagram repeated for ever.

Comment: That's because in the while loop you never increment `f`, and so you always print `j[0]`. Also, why not iterate through the items like `for i in j: print(i)`?

Comment: I'm really really new at programming i know exactly only the basics @reti43

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you don't increment f at the end. 
Do it rather like:

```
for item in j:
   print( item )
```

The other thing is, you overwrite j in every loop. Are you sure you wanted it like that?

Answer (score 0):

There were several problems with your loop construct, including reinitializing your results every time.  Try a simpler approach where things are already the type they want to be rather than constantly converting.  And not everything you want to do requires a loop:

```
import random

item = input("Name? ")

length = len(item)

anagrams = set()

for repetitions in range(length**2):
    anagrams.add(''.join(random.sample(item, length)))

print("\n".join(anagrams))
```

However, these anagrams are not exhaustive (the random nature of this means some will be missed.)  And they're not really anagrams as there's no dictionary to help generate actual words, just random letters.

Comment: This is so simplier and better working, thanks to y'all , @phev8
Sorry about the "anagrams" it was just a word scrambler in the end xp.
I'll have to spend a lot of time understanding this code